# How to bring vim back to foreground in Powershell

Tags: vim, powershell

1. launch vim from powershell
2. hit `control+z` (you are dropped back to powershell, vim is in background)
3. ??? **How do you bring Vim back to foreground?**

EDIT: I have tried `fg`

Comment: Did you try `fg`?

Answer (score 1):

`exit` did the trick.  It looks vim is actually opening a new shell rather than suspending.